# Scalability issue - DAO do seq scan for eventByTag

Tags: akka-persistence, lagom

we are building our product on lagom and one day suddenly we saw high CPU usage.

We are using lagom version 3.10

We found that it is because of eventsByTag query on Journal table which do a sequential scan. and if events in the table is more than 1 million, it will screw the system.

Is this the desired behavior or am i missing something basic here

Comment: I don't think that's the right Lagom version as the latest stable version is 1.4.6. But there is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc/issues/194) in Akka Persistence Jdbc.

Comment: its been taken by the akka persistence jdbc team , also a workaround for Lagom has been added (we change ilike to = as lagom add only 1 tag)

Answer (score 0):

its been taken by the akka persistence jdbc team , also a workaround for Lagom has been added (we change ilike to = as lagom add only 1 tag)